# OS X configuring Apache for new website: URL not found

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, website

I'm trying to setup my confguration so I can develop a website to test an MVC architecture (based on [this example](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)). My problem is that I can only access my index.php if I dont specify any on the url. 
My website location is on /Users/[my user]/Projects/workspace/Spike and to avoid problems with permissions I've added a symbolic link /Library/WebServer/Documents/spike to point to the website folder mentioned above. I have also setup a new VirtualHost on httpd.conf with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost project1>
        ServerName project1
        DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/spike
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added a new entry on /etc/hosts pointing project1 to 127.0.0.1.
On my website root I have a .htaccess with the following content, which should be forwarding all request to my index.php file (right now containing only an echo "Hello World"):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So, my problem is that if I try to access with "http://project1/" everything works ok. If I try to access with "http://project1/something" (and so on) I'll get the following error:

> The requested URL /something was not found on this server.

Can anyone help me out here? 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewrite rules are ignored. You can access `index.php` directly, but not the files that don't actually exist, because their request paths aren't being rewritten.

You need to specify `AllowOverride All` in the web server configuration files (like `httpd.conf`), otherwise setting rewrite rules in `.htaccess` files is ignored.

The directive is usually there within all default `<Directory ...>` blocks, just set them from `None` to `All`. Restart Apache via *System Preferences » Sharing* and try again.

Comment: AllOverride All will incur a performance hit as Apache will look for .htaccess files in all accessed directories.